# FireBase Crashlytics not providing full stacktrace on iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics

I find that most of the time, the stack trace provided by Firebase Crashlytics is not complete. The trace I see on Firebase console has missing function calls in between. This is for the release version. Has anyone noticed it and anything can be done to fix it?

For instance, here is a sample crash trace:

[image]

function CapturePipeline.applySettings() is never called from CapturePipeline.init() in the code. So what is Firebase showing?

Comment: Do you mind specifying what calls you're expecting to see, that are missing?

Comment: I updated the question, please check.

Comment: Symbolication appears to be working correctly, but if you're able to reproduce a situation where you can crash the app locally and can get crash logs that differ from the ones that Crashlytics produces the please reach out to Firebase support.
Function "CapturePipeline.applySettings()" never being called from "CapturePipeline.init()" could very well be true, but we it's difficult to diagnose a problem just off that.